# MethodBuilder.CreateDelegate throws exception:'Derived classes must provide an implementation.'

Tags: c#, typebuilder

I want to get an instance of delegate from a global dynamic method, when I do the final step, invoke the method of CreateDelegate from MethodBuilder class, It throws such exception, I tried to locate the code source of .net framework to find why, but failed, will any one could help me to resolve this problem?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        //THESE CODE COPIES FROM MSDN
        AssemblyBuilder assembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("TempAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);
        ModuleBuilder module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("TempModule");
        MethodBuilder method = module.DefineGlobalMethod
                    ("MyMethod1", MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public,
                        null, null);
        ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();
        generator.EmitWriteLine("Hello World from global method.");
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        // Fix up the 'TempModule' module .
        module.CreateGlobalFunctions();

        //ERROR:
        Action action = method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), null) as Action;
        action();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few minutes, I become understand that the global method is designed for Visual Basic.Net.
However, you can access it with c# also, so this get a problem that each method must have a declaring type in c#, so if you try to use such functions, you will always get such exception.

Comment: And I think this question can be closed now, no more answers needed, thank you, I leave this answer here to help some other people who get the same question future.